# Compile Problem with MySQL C API on MAC OS X 10.6

Tags: mysql, macos, api, g++

i've a Problem with MySQL C API and Mac OS X 10.6. When i want to compile a SQL Client Program, it aborts with this Error Message

> ld: library not found for -lmysqlclient
>
> collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

I compile with this command:

> g++ -I /usr/local/mysql/include/ -L /usr/local/mysql/lib/ -lmysqlclient main.cpp

I've tried the Headers and Librarys in different locations - no effect
I've downloaded the headers and the Library from an other Destination - Same effect as before

Any Ideas what i am doing wrong?
If there is a thread allready i want to excuse (nothing found in search)!

Greeting, Dennis

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So after many days, of not intensive work ;-) here's the fault:
the compiler doesn't accept the library if it is in the standard install directory. I copied the include and lib files into `/usr/local/include` and `/usr/local/lib` . Now it compiles without errors :-)

I don't know why it only works in the standard paths but however now it works.

Dennis