# How to install MySQL Connector/C on Mac OS X?

Tags: mysql, c, macos

I'm writing an app in C that requires MySQL interaction, so I downloaded the Connector/C archive from the official website, and it contains bin, lib and include folders, but I don't know where to install them.
I could copy the include files into my project folder, but where can I put the lib file so that my compiled binary (and other binaries) can find it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is confusing, isn't it.. don't know why they don't make this more clear.

The lib/ files go in /usr/local/lib
The include/ files go in /usr/local/include
The bin/ files go in /usr/local/bin

The /usr/.. directory isn't visible through finder afaik so you have to go at it via commandline.  Best of luck

Also, in your Xcode project, make sure you add a Linked Library by going to your Target's settings, General, then adding Linked Library "libmysqlclient.dylib"

Comment: You can hit Shift-Cmd-G in any Finder window to get to `/usr`

Comment: In Xcode after adding the Linked Library, I had to add `/usr/local/include` to the Header Search Paths.  Right click on project and Get Info, select the build tab, then scroll down to find the Search Paths section.

Comment: Note you're [not supposed to put the files directly in `/usr/include/`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2892609/compile-problem-with-mysql-c-api-on-mac-os-x-10-6), which was a mistake I made. Always use `/usr/local/include` for your own files.

Comment: When adding to header search path make sure to set it as recursive

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively, to do everything on the commandline by "mv", you could also execute (on cmdline):

```
defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles TRUE
```

and

```
killall Finder
```

to make the hidden folder /usr (and everything else) visible.

After placing your connector files (like Nektarios explicitly discribed where) and closing all "hidden folder - finder windows", execute on your cmd:

```
defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles FALSE
```

and again

```
killall Finder
```

to hide what have to be hidden.