# remote database for, e.g., messaging among users -- need learning resources

Tags: ios, remote-server

I am working on a app that will need a remote database for purposes including storing messages users have sent to one another and cataloging user-searchable data.

I have been looking for tutorials and reading stackoverflow answers, but I have not found a viable starting point for learning how to do this. I am expecting this to be a ton of work, and that's fine, but I need thorough guides.

I read at [XCode Objective-C connect to MySQL database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4858274/xcode-objective-c-connect-to-mysql-database), which is 2 years old, that you need a web server layer between your app and your MySQL database. But I haven't found useful information beyond that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might consider a solution like [Parse](https://www.parse.com/products/data). It's free to try and you won't have to deal with the hassle of configuring a dedicated server, writing an API to access the resources, basic caching, etc... Parse seems to be mainly a key-value store though, so it might be too limited for your purposes - you'd have to see for yourself.

Comment: Parse seems very promising. Thanks.