# How to install MySQL Connector C++ for Mac OS X (using Terminal)?

Tags: mysql, mysql-connector, mysql-connect

I downloaded the MySQL Connector/C++ source tree, which has an 'include' and a 'lib' directory. Now I'm following the README.txt. I download CMake which launches as a program with a UI. The first step of the installation says

```
me@host:/path/to/mysql-connector-cpp> cmake .
```

I can't make much sense of this. Does this mean to cd into the directory of the source tree and then run cmake? On what file?

I found this [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4615442/how-to-install-mysql-connector-c-on-mac-os-x) and [these instructions](http://www.davenicholas.me.uk/blog/view_post/29/How-to-c-mysql-mac-osx) but they seem unique to installation using the Xcode UI and I don't know how to apply them in the Terminal. I plan on compiling / running the C++ with g++.

Thanks,

fertileneutrino

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it does mean - go to the root directory of the source distribution and type `cmake .`. As for the file, the default file for CMake is `CMakeList.txt`, so you don't have to specify it. You can also run cmake in other directories and specify the path to the source root directory as a second argument. For example, a very common way of building projects is this:

```
$ cd project-sources
$ mkdir build
$ cd build
$ cmake ..
$ make
$ make install
```

That way, all generated files can be simply nuked by removing the build directory, for example: `rm -rf build`.

Comment: Typing `cmake .` yields `/directory does not appear to contain CMakeLists.txt.` Should I put the file in the directory, or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Got it - I was running `cmake .` in the wrong directory. I have to download the source directory which is different than the MAC OS X distribution

Comment: Hell MySQL really is different from OS X :)

Comment: er sorry, I meant the MySQL-connect OS X distribution