# Connecting AWS RDS and server instance in iOS app Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

I am building an app for the first time and it requires a back-end connection with the database. I've established a working EC2 and RDS instance in AWS (also trying out for the first time). I don't know how exactly to establish a connection in Xcode with a .php file, there's a couple missing holes in my knowledge that I hope someone can clear up. Every online resource I've looked up doesn't use the exact stack that I'm using so I get confused as to where to go from here.

**How would I go about connecting to my Amazon RDS (mySQL) credentials inside my XCode project? Also would I save a separate .php file with the server connection and insert the URL of the file from my local directory? I know I have an endpoint URL provided by RDS, I'm just confused as to how to go about connecting all of this in order to start the POST/GET requests. There isn't a clear tutorial on this, so hope to get some answers here.**

Answer (score 5):

The reason why you can not find tutorial on this subject is because it is not considered a good architecture practice to connect backend databases directly from mobile applications.  Not only you have the problem of providing the mobile application with the database credentials, in a secure way, but also it would oblige you to implement the access and authorization logic in your mobile app and will create a hard dependency between your mobile and the database endpoint.  What if it crashes ?  What if you need more CPU/Storage on the server side to accommodate client requests etc ..

The correct architecture is to expose the data required by your mobile app through a API.  AWS has several options to let you create an API (API Gateway and AppSync).  In both cases, the `amplify` command line will generate the XCode Swift code for you for easy integration with your app.

See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-generate-sdk-ios-swift.html

See an iOS code sample here https://github.com/sebsto/reinvent2018-mob320 (it doe snot have RDS integration in the backend, I will leave this as an exercise for you)

Searching the web, you will find other persons having post similar questions and having received similar answers :

- https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=136902
- [How to connect amazon RDS in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21624853/how-to-connect-amazon-rds-in-ios)

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, in the simplest terms, appreciate it.

Comment: You're welcome, do not forget to mark the answer as accepted if this answers your question